# Change platform in .NET from 3.5 down to 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, target

I have a C# project  in VS 2008. I changed target framework from 3.5 down to 2.0.I also have a set up project with net framework 2.0 required. But after installing program in another PC, i get an error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly System.Core, version 3.5.0.0.. etc...

I don't understand why I change target framework to 2.0 and no importing System.Core in reference. But i import System.IO, is it problem? How can i use net framework 2.0. Thank for advances. Sorry because of my bad English.

Comment: Have you checked the versions of the references you have in the project? Are you using LINQ or some other 3.5 feature?

Comment: Here are assembly in reference i have: System, system.data, system.web, system.xml,system.drawing,system.window.forms,system.deployment,gecko-13,ionic.zip. And these are my imported namespace:"using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Gecko;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using Ionic.Zip;"

Comment: Click each reference in the project in the solution explorer and check the properties windows for the version. Another way is to right click the project, click unload; after the project has unloaded, right click it again and choose edit. You'll get the project file xml code in a text editor and you'll be able to see the reference versions used if you search for "reference".

Comment: I have checked each reference and all of them have "runtime version"=2.0.50727
    Here are xml file after unloading project
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />

Comment: @TrầnMinh To add details edit your question. Don't use the comments for that.

Answer (score 1):

See if your references in the project tab have any versions other than 2.0:

[image: Example on where to look]

I assume you first tried to re-target here:

[image: re-target framework]

Comment: Sorry but i can't find this window in my project tabs i use VS 2008 C#. How can i open it.

Comment: Ah, ok. This is from VS2010. See if not this can help you: http://www.vtc.com/products/IntroductiontoMicrosoftVisualStudio2008/VisualStudioIDE/83632

Answer (score 0):

System.Core will not support directly by Framework 2.0.............

Comment: Check your references in Solution Explorer

Comment: I posted my references at above comment.You can see.

Comment: Please go with this [Link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/525663/cannot-remove-system-core-dll-reference-from-a-vs2010-project), it may help you :)